# Making only one retrofit request and sharing the observable

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to fetch the access token from my server. But calling the API multiple times will end up invalidating the previous access token(s) and I may arrive at a dead-lock (if 2 requests are constantly fetching new tokens before either one completes).

To be clear, I am not interested in thread safety per se- My `login` method is always called from the main thread.

I have implemented it using java's `AtomicReference` as follows:

```
private AtomicReference<Observable<ServerToken>> mTokenObservableRef;
// ...

public Observable<ServerToken> login(String facebookAccessToken) {
    LogWrapper.d(TAG, "login " + facebookAccessToken);

    Observable<ServerToken> tokenObservable = mTokenApi.registerViaFacebook(facebookAccessToken)
            .doOnNext((serverToken) -> {
                AuthorizationHelper.storeServerToken(serverToken);
                mTokenObservableRef.set(null);
            })
            .cache(1); // prevent new calls when new subscriptions take place
    mTokenObservableRef.compareAndSet(null, tokenObservable); // set to tokenObservable only if it was null
    return mTokenObservableRef.get();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why will the request to the api be performed multiple times?

Comment: The method is called from a lot of places. When a `401 Unauthorized` is received, all of the pending requests will call this one first.